# How change the size of UI Chip dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In the following example, I am trying to change the size the UI chip in dynamically in order to respond to the font size of its parents using the `em` `css` unit.

My goal: I want to do something like this

```
style={{size:'1em'}}
```

**My problem**: the chip element in material-ui is not resizable like most of the material-UI components.

I tried:

1. `style={{transform:'scale(1em)'}}` but it did not work at all. I don't know how to change the anchor point of transform.
2. I also tried to create my own chip with `<img style={{float: 'left', width: '1em', borderRadius: '50%',}}/>` but it does not look original as the material UI chip.

```
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip'

function Chips() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.info('You clicked the delete icon.')
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.info('You clicked the Chip.')
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>
        <Chip
          //style={{size:'1em'}}
          avatar={<Avatar alt="Natacha" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />}
          label="Deletable"
          onDelete={handleDelete}
        />
      </h1>

      <h4>
        <Chip
          //style={{size:'1em'}}
          avatar={<Avatar alt="Natacha" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />}
          label="Deletable"
          onDelete={handleDelete}
        />
      </h4>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: See [Chip API - CSS Material UI](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/#css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently, `Chip` doesn't support the prop for size (*Hope they support it in the future* ).
For this, you've to make your own custom component. I've created one name `CustomChip`.

In this, pass a prop named `size`, and the rest of the sizes of the chip scales accordingly.

#### CustomChip.js

```
function CustomChip(props) {
  const { size = 1, ...restProps } = props;
  const classes = useStyles({ size });

  return (
    <Chip
      className={classes.root}
      classes={{ avatar: classes.avatar, deleteIcon: classes.deleteIcon }}
      {...restProps}
    />
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    fontSize: (props) => `${props.size * 0.8125}rem`,
    height: (props) => `${props.size * 32}px`,
    borderRadius: "9999px"
  },
  avatar: {
    "&&": {
      height: (props) => `${props.size * 24}px`,
      width: (props) => `${props.size * 24}px`,
      fontSize: (props) => `${props.size * 0.75}rem`
    }
  },
  deleteIcon: {
    height: (props) => `${props.size * 22}px`,
    width: (props) => `${props.size * 22}px`,
    color: "green"
  }
}));
```

Here the provided size gets multiplied by the default sizes of the parts.

*use:-*

```
<CustomChip
    size={2}
    avatar={<Avatar alt="Natacha" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />}
    label="Deletable"
    onDelete={handleDelete}
/>
```

Working sandbox link:-

[image: Edit crazy-blackwell-987it]

Comment: Oh thank you so much that is really great job. [You may list this](https://github.com/aliscie/Notion-so-clone) This a github repo where I am trying to clone notion, and I am looking for contributors like

Comment: I am trying to use em not rem. Also, I don't want to add size value, but I need it to dynamically responded to the font size of its parents so I made [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-tharp-oc4x6)  but I got a problem with the alignment ![alignment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vwhKsh5i8jhHL-SjLJyaVsdcQTs8aPlR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'll try to fix this one.

Comment: Hi @Rajiv, could you please take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695062/wrapping-text-in-mui-chip-gets-out-of-the-background-colour

Answer (score 1):

Due to `makeStyles()` [deprecation in the v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506133/difference-between-mui-material-styles-and-mui-styles/69508854#69508854), it is recommended to use a newer styling solution `sx` or `styled`.

Example with custom component and `sx`:

```
import React from 'react';

import { ChipProps } from '@mui/material/Chip/Chip';
import { Chip } from '@mui/material';

type ChipAtomProps = ChipProps & {
  scale?: number;
};

const ChipAtom: React.FC<ChipAtomProps> = ({
  id,
  className,
  variant,
  scale = 1,
  avatar,
  label,
}) => {
  const scaledChipSx = {
    height: `${scale * 32}px`,
    borderRadius: `${scale * 16}px`,
    '& .MuiChip-label': {
      paddingRight: `${scale * 12}px`,
      paddingLeft: `${scale * 12}px`,
      fontSize: `${scale * 0.8125}rem`,
    },
    '& .MuiChip-avatar': {
      width: `${scale * 24}px`,
      height: `${scale * 24}px`,
      fontSize: `${scale * 0.75}rem`,
    },
  };

  return (
    <Chip
      id={id}
      className={className}
      variant={variant}
      avatar={avatar}
      label={label}
      sx={scaledChipSx}
    />
  );
};

export default ChipAtom;
```