# Difference between @mui/material/styles and @mui/styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In Material-UI v5, some API uses are imported from `@mui/material/styles`, like `useTheme`. And some API uses are imported from `@mui/styles`, like `makeStyles`. Can I use those style-related APIs from only one library, either `@mui/styles` or `@mui/material/styles`? Because, in Material-UI v4, I imported all style-related APIs from `'@material-ui/core/styles'` or `'material-ui/styles'`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Normally in v4, you'd import the style API from `@material-ui/core/styles`. This one uses JSS behind the scene:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

In v5, they [changed the brand name to MUI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27666). As a result, the package name changed too:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

But MUI v5 also drops the support for JSS (which `makeStyles`/`withStyles` are using), so they move those APIs to a legacy package called `@mui/styles`. (They plan to remove this API in v6, but there are some pushback. See [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26571) issue for more info)

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

And encourage the users to adopt a newer styling solution (`sx`, `styled`) using emotion as a default style engine:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

So in summary, the difference between the `@mui/material/styles` and `@mui/styles` is that:

| [`@mui/styles`](https://mui.com/styles/basics/#main-content) | `@mui/material/styles` |
| --- | --- |
| Doesn't come with a default theme, need `createTheme` / `ThemeProvider` | Come with a default material theme (as opposed to the other planned [theme](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27825#issuecomment-921377969)) |
| Legacy styling package | Depends on the new [`@mui/system`](https://mui.com/system/basics/#main-content) package |
| Powered by JSS | Powered by emotion (as a default style engine) |
| Has `makeStyles`/`withStyles` | Doesn't have `makeStyles`/`withStyles`, has `styled` instead |

You should not mix `@mui/styles` with `@mui/material/styles`. Choose one styling solution and stick with it because duplicated classNames from different style libraries can lead to unexpected side-effects and hard-to-find bugs. If you're creating a new project or having a small v4 project, I recommend migrating completely to the emotion solution to avoid adding extra bundle size because MUI component uses emotion, not JSS anymore in the new version.

### References

- https://mui.com/styles/basics/#main-content
- https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#heading-mui-material-styles

Comment: +1 This is really informative and detailed (but also point-to-point). This clears all my doubts while upgrading from v4 to v5.

Answer (score 0):

In version 4 they used:=>
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

but changed in material UI version 5 to:=>
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';

because they changed the brand name

AND simply you can use ==========================

npm install @mui/styles --save --force

import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

==========================================