# What is the type of theme in Material-UI version 5?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm updating my project to [MUI version 5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4). It is recommended to use emotion CSS. I want to use the `theme` property. Now typescript is asking for type for `theme`. The version below does not work. How can I provide a type?

```
import { Theme } from "@mui/material"

const Root = styled('div')(({ theme: Theme }) => ({
  background: theme.palette.grey[50],
}))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you happen to import the `styled` API from [`@mui/styles`](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#mui-styles), then it wouldn't work because it's not provided with a MUI theme out-of-the-box. You need to `createTheme` and pass it to the `ThemeProvider` yourself, then augment the type of `DefaultTheme` because by default it's an empty interface:

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/styles' {
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

But be aware that it's not recommended to use the legacy package `@mui/styles`. See more detail on my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508854/9449426).

---

In case you've already imported `styled` from `@mui/material/styles`: Since you're using typescript, remove the `Theme` type, the `styled` function can infer the type of the property `theme` in the callback, so you don't have to do anything:

```
const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  background: theme.palette.grey[50],
}))
```

But theoretically, if the `theme` is untyped, this is how you add it:

```
const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }: { theme: Theme }) => ({
  background: theme.palette.grey[50],
}))
```