# Wrapping text in Material UI chip gets out of the background colour

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am facing one problem when I wrap the label inside Material UI Chip then the text goes out of the background color.

**Question : Is there any way what i can stop the automatic responsive behaviour of dataGrid and just add horizontal scroll ?**

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

**Here is the code** :

```
import { Chip, useTheme } from "@mui/material"
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

import { observer } from "mobx-react"
import { useMemo } from "react"

import { exhaustiveCheck } from "src/lib/exhaustive-check"

interface IProps {
    label: string
    state: "positive" | "neutral" | "negative" | "info" | "other"
}


export type IStatusChipProps = IProps

    export const StatusChip = observer((props: IProps) => {
    const theme = useTheme()

    const color = useMemo(() => {
        switch (props.state) {
            case "negative":
                return theme.palette.utility.rustRedFaded.main
            case "positive":
                return theme.palette.utility.appleFaded.main
            case "neutral":
                return theme.palette.utility.orangeFaded.main
            case "info":
                return theme.palette.utility.blueFaded.main
            case "other":
                return theme.palette.grey[300]
            default:
                exhaustiveCheck(props.state)
                return theme.palette.grey[100]
        }
    }, [theme, props.state])

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
        createStyles({
            root: {
                backgroundColor: color,
                "& .MuiChip-label": {
                    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
                        overflowWrap: "break-word",
                        whiteSpace: "pre-wrap",
                    },
                },
            },
        }),
    )
    const classes = useStyles()

    return <Chip className={classes.root} label={props.label} />
})
```

The background color is basically dynamic, Based on the status of the item the color gets added up to the chip's background.

Please let me know how can I handle this scenario.

**As on the desktop screen it looks as intended** :

[image]

Comment: It looks like there was a proposed solution [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/18587) using the label tag, however it may have not made it into the core. It looks like you are pulling styles from MUI 4, but importing the Chip from MUI 5. This could be an issue but possibly not ...

Comment: Hi @Jamie_D, In that link they are not wrapping the text but they are adding ... after certain width

Comment: There are [some examples here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0on28qwo8v?file=/demo.js:305-467) ... Take note of the `styles` constant

Comment: margin: theme.spacing.unit is not working for me